# Windows 8 live streaming to a server?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I do live streaming (from webcamera) to a server in Windows 8 Metro App? Is there any SDK's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an SDK.  See the Real time Communication sample for an idea of how to do what you want... http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Communication-Sample-eac73290

Comment: Big thanks, and I have question: if I replace "stsp://localhost" on remote host, will it work?